# Dereferencing a pointer created with ffi.addressof in Python CFFI (C *-operator equivalent?)

Tags: python, c, pointers, dereference, python-cffi

```
values = ffi.new( "int[]", 10 )
pValue = ffi.addressof( pInt, 0 )
```

With Python CFFI, the code above creates a pointer to the first element of `values` as `pValue`.

You can then access its content with `values[ 0 ]`, but this is not really transparent and it is sometimes inconvenient to keep track of what indice is what value.

Is there anything such as the C `*-operator`, a function or something else, to dereference `pValue` and access its content directly?

In other languages... :

```
// In C:
// =====

int values[ 10 ] = {0};
int* pValue = &( values[ 0 ] );

func_with_pointer_to_int_as_param( pValue );

printf( "%d\n", *pValue );

-------------------------------------------------------------

# In Python with CFFI:
# ====================

values = ffi.new( "int[]", 10 )
pValue = ffi.addressof( values, 0 )

lib.func_with_pointer_to_int_as_param( pValue ) #lib is where the C functions are

print values[ 0 ] #Something else than that? Sort of "ffi.contentof( pValue )"?
```

**EDIT :**
Here is a use case where it is useful:

I find it more readable to do:

```
pC_int = ffi.new( "int[]", 2 )
pType  = ffi.addressof( pC_int, 0 )
pValue = ffi.addressof( pC_int, 1 )
...

# That you access with:
print "Type: {0}, value: {1}".format( pC_int[ 0 ], pC_int[ 1 ] )
```

Rather than:

```
pInt_type = ffi.new( "int[]", 1 )
pType     = ffi.addressof( pInt_type, 0 )

pInt_value = ffi.new( "int[]", 1 )
pValue     = ffi.addressof( pInt_value, 0 )

...

# That you access with:
print "Type: {0}, value: {1}".format( pInt_type[ 0 ], pInt_value[ 0 ] )
```

And I guess the former is faster. But, when you want to access the values it makes it inconvenient to remember like "ok type is number 0" etc...

Comment: In C,  `*x` is completely equivalent to `x[0]`.

Comment: Yes. I added a use case where it would be useful to have a direct dereference of a pointer to a CData.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  What would you like to do?  Is that what you'd write in C as `*pType`, `*pValue`?  Then you can write it `pType[0]`, `pValue[0]`.  Of course you can also define and use your own function `def contentof(p): return p[0]`.

Comment: Problem solved, my bad, I did not understand what you meant with your first comment. Could you write a quick something like "`pValue` being the alias of `ffi.addressof( pC_int, 0 )`, you can access its content with `pValue[ 0 ]`" as an answer so the question can be solved? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the syntax `*pType` is always equivalent to `pType[0]`.  So say you would like to do something like:

```
print "Type: {0}, value: {1}".format( *pType, *pValue )
```

but of course this is not valid Python syntax.  The solution is that you can always rewrite it like this, which becomes valid Python syntax:

```
print "Type: {0}, value: {1}".format( pType[0], pValue[0] )
```